# chronoforms return null value for data area

Tags: database, null, chronoforms

I use chronoforms with my joomla site. When I test the form everything works fine. But in production when users submit the form, there is lost data. Those data are not inserted into my mysql database. My database is a remote database.

Does anyone run in something like this?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a debug action to your form which may help in diagnosing where the problem lies.

Comment: Thank Neil. Well, I did it too, and found out that all the fields in the data array have their data present. The problem is that, even with this, some part of the data is missing when saved in the database. Sometimes all the fields in the database are filled and sometimes some or all are missing. When I run tests I have no issues, but some users try too and have these issues. I thought it was because of the internet connection or maybe the web browser, but I really don't know. On ten rows saved in the database, at least one contains empty fields.
Thanks!